# Compare single array value

Tags: php

How can I do a comparison when my array returns value with index.

Returned value is  Array ( [isMember] => 0 ) and I want do to a comparison on the value only

```
   if ($memberStatus == 0)
   {
     print_r($memberStatus);
   }
```

Comment: What kind of comparison? The index? The value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array like this:

```
$data = [ 'isMember' => 0, 'data1' => 1, 'data2' => 2 /* ... */ ];
```

You can access single elements by using the name of the array and write the key in square brackets:

```
// change isMember to whatever key-value pair you need
$memberStatus = $data['isMember'];

if ($memberStatus === 0)
{
    print 'user is a member';
}

else
{
    print 'user it not a member';
}
```

Comment: Much better explanation. Was a little unsure of what was being asked I guess :D

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

Index Array's value can be access by using corresponding **index** value where as an Associative Array's value can be access by using corresponding **key** along with array name and in between square brackets that is

**arrayName["index-value"]**

or

**arrayName["key-name"]**.

You may refer to the following code.

**Code**

```
     //For Associative Array
     
     $arrayOne = array(
         'keyone' => 'a',
         'keytwo' => 'b',
         'keythird' => 'c'
     );

     if ($arrayOne['keyone'] == 'a') {
         print_r($arrayOne['keyone']);
         //output a
     }
```

**OR**

```
   //For Index Array

     $arrayOne = array('a', 'b', 'c');

     if ($arrayOne[0] == 'a') {
        print_r($arrayOne[0]);
       //output a
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
$myArray = array(
  'isMember' => 0
);

if ( $myArray['isMember'] == 0 ) {
  print_r($myArray['isMember']);
}
```

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for an array literal. Either `array('isMember' => 0)` or `['isMember' => 0]`

Comment: And typo in `pritn_r`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a key inside an array? Then you need:

```
echo array_key_exists(9, [1=>'nope',2=>'nope',3=>'nope',9=>'yah']) ? 'Yes it does' : 'it doesn\'t';
```

Otherwise you are looking for:

```
echo in_array("my value", ["my value", "a wrong value", "another wrong one"]) ? 'yush' : 'naaaaah';
```

Either way you can use both in a `if` statement rather than a thernary operator.

Comment: OP stated he wants to check for the value only

Comment: As I stated on my answer, `in_array()` function is what he is looking for, but since we touched that land already is good to know what `array_key_exists()` function can do for him as well

Comment: Thats true, but thats not what he asked for. He said he has given an array which HAS a key isMember and not MAY have a key isMember. Nevertheless its good to know yes.

Comment: Is not about solving HIS particular problem but to provide him the means to do that... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which type of array you need to compare because there are generally 2 different types of them:

**Indexed**
- You pick numerical index which do you want to compare

```
 $array = array("admin", "moderator", "user");

 if ($array[0] == "user") {
    // CODE
 }
```

**Associative**
- You pick the string key which do you want to compare

```
 $array = array( "id1" => "member", "id2" => "not member","id3" => "user");

 if ($array["id2"] == "not member") {
     // CODE
 }
```